# Get more than one dimension with numpy take function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've got a one dimensional array (n) called edges and want to insert the values by the index from the vertices array (n,3)

```
vertices = [[ 1.25, 4.321, -4], [2, -5, 3.32], [23.3, 43, 12], [32, 4, -23]]

edges = [1, 3, 2, 0]


result = [[2, -5, 3.32], [32, 4, -23], [23.3, 43, 12], [ 1.25, 4.321, -4]]
```

I tried np.take(vertices, edges) but It doesn't work for multi dimensional arrays.

Comment: That seems wrong : `[ 1.25, 4,321, -4]`, could be `4.321`?

Comment: What do you mean by "insert the values by the index from the vertices array"?

Comment: And why is the third element of the result `[2, -5, 3.32]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`take` with axis parameter works

```
In [313]: vertices=np.array(vertices)
In [314]: edges=[1,3,2,0]
In [315]: np.take(vertices, edges,0)
Out[315]: 
array([[  2.   ,  -5.   ,   3.32 ],
       [ 32.   ,   4.   , -23.   ],
       [ 23.3  ,  43.   ,  12.   ],
       [  1.25 ,   4.321,  -4.   ]])
In [316]: vertices[edges,:]
Out[316]: 
array([[  2.   ,  -5.   ,   3.32 ],
       [ 32.   ,   4.   , -23.   ],
       [ 23.3  ,  43.   ,  12.   ],
       [  1.25 ,   4.321,  -4.   ]])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use **indexing** here:

```
vertices[edges]
#       ^     ^ indexing
```

If you **index with a list**, then numpy will reshuffle the original matrix such that the highest dimension here follows the indices as specified by `edges`.

like:

```
>>> vertices = np.array([[ 1.25, 4.321, -4], [2, -5, 3.32], [23.3, 43, 12], [32, 4, -23]])
>>> edges = [1, 3, 2, 0]
>>> vertices[edges]
array([[  2.   ,  -5.   ,   3.32 ],
       [ 32.   ,   4.   , -23.   ],
       [ 23.3  ,  43.   ,  12.   ],
       [  1.25 ,   4.321,  -4.   ]])
>>> vertices[edges].base is None
True
```

The fact that `base` is `None` means that this does **not generate a view**, it makes a copy of the matrix (with filtered/reordered rows). Changes you thus later make to the *elements* of `vertices` will not change the elements of the result of `vertices[edges]` (given you make the copy before altering `vertices` of course).

Comment: thank you it works. It seems like hpauljs solution is a little bit faster