# Loop over array and get more than one dimension with indexing

Tags: python, numpy

Referring to my previous (solved) question here [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44531558/get-more-than-one-dimension-with-numpy-take-function/44532087#44532087/), I now want to do that operation on a multidimensional array.

```
vertices = [[ 1.25, 4.321, -4], [2, -5, 3.32], [23.3, 43, 12], [32, 4, -23]]

newedges = [[1, 3, 2, 0], [2, 1, 3, 0], [1, 2, 0, 3]]

newresult = [[[2, -5, 3.32], [32, 4, -23], [23.3, 43, 12], [ 1.25, 4.321, -4]], [[23.3, 43, 12], [2, -5, 3.32], [32, 4, -23], [ 1.25, 4.321, -4]], [[2, -5, 3.32], [23.3, 43, 12], [ 1.25, 4.321, -4], [32, 4, -23]]]
```

I want to get back an array with the same shape as "newedges" but with the indexes replaced by the vertices (-> newresult).

I tried:

```
list = ()
arr = np.ndarray(newedges.shape[0])

for idx, element in enumerate(newedges):

    arr[idx] = vertices[newedges[idx]]

list.append(arr)
```

But get an index error (with my real data, that's why there is an index 61441):

```
IndexError: index 61441 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 2
```

Comment: `vertices` is a multidimensional array and the indices you're passing to its first axis is out of the range.

Comment: Previous question link seems inaccurate/broken. It currently points to http://www.example.com/

Comment: @vishal I corrected it

Comment: @Kasramvd good to know but I don't know how to solve that

Comment: You want your output to be a numpy object, or a python list? My guess is you would want a python list of numpy 2-d objects
Also, you haven't put sufficient number of brackets enclosing `newresult`

Comment: Sorry, I have to be more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
import numpy as np

vertices = [[ 1.25, 4.321, -4], [2, -5, 3.32], [23.3, 43, 12], [32, 4, -23]]
vertices= np.array(vertices)
newedges = [[1, 3, 2, 0], [2, 1, 3, 0], [1, 2, 0, 3]]

newresult = []

for edgeset in newedges:
    updatededges = np.take(vertices, edgeset, 0)
    newresult.append(updatededges)

print newresult
"""
newresult = [array([[  2.   ,  -5.   ,   3.32 ],
       [ 32.   ,   4.   , -23.   ],
       [ 23.3  ,  43.   ,  12.   ],
       [  1.25 ,   4.321,  -4.   ]]),

 array([[ 23.3  ,  43.   ,  12.   ],
       [  2.   ,  -5.   ,   3.32 ],
       [ 32.   ,   4.   , -23.   ],
       [  1.25 ,   4.321,  -4.   ]]),

 array([[  2.   ,  -5.   ,   3.32 ],
       [ 23.3  ,  43.   ,  12.   ],
       [  1.25 ,   4.321,  -4.   ],
       [ 32.   ,   4.   , -23.   ]])]
"""
```

Another advice: do not use python keywords like `list` as variable names. This goes for any programming language

Answer (score 1):

instead of this  `list= ()` you have to use `result = []`

replace: `arr = np.ndarray(newedges.shape[0])`

to: `arr = np.ndarray(newedges[0]).shape`

```
for idx, element in enumerate(newedges):
    arr[idx] = vertices[newedges[0][idx]]

result.append(arr)
```

you got IndexError because you pass list of list `vertices[newedges[idx]]` but list required index or slice `vertices[newedges[0][idx]]`

Hope this answer is as you want.

Answer (score 0):

On the line 3, you missed one ]

before :

```
newedges = [[1, 3, 2, 0], [2, 1, 3, 0], [1, 2, 0, 3]
```

after :

```
newedges = [[1, 3, 2, 0], [2, 1, 3, 0], [1, 2, 0, 3]]
```

if you don't do that, the line 5 is considered as a string.

then you have other problems, to saw what it is, use [that](http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=vertices%20%3D%20%5B%5B%201.25,%204.321,%20-4%5D,%20%5B2,%20-5,%203.32%5D,%20%5B23.3,%2043,%2012%5D,%20%5B32,%204,%20-23%5D%5D%0A%0Anewedges%20%3D%20%5B%5B1,%203,%202,%200%5D,%20%5B2,%201,%203,%200%5D,%20%5B1,%202,%200,%203%5D%5D%0A%0Anewresult%20%3D%20%5B%5B2,%20-5,%203.32%5D,%20%5B32,%204,%20-23%5D,%20%5B23.3,%2043,%2012%5D,%20%5B%201.25,%204.321,%20-4%5D%5D,%20%5B%5B23.3,%2043,%2012%5D,%20%5B2,%20-5,%203.32%5D,%20%5B32,%204,%20-23%5D,%20%5B%201.25,%204.321,%20-4%5D%5D,%20%5B%5B2,%20-5,%203.32%5D,%20%5B23.3,%2043,%2012%5D,%20%5B%201.25,%204.321,%20-4%5D,%20%5B32,%204,%20-23%5D%5D%0A%0Alist%20%3D%20%28%29%0Aarr%20%3D%20np.ndarray%28newedges.shape%5B0%5D%29%0A%0Afor%20idx,%20element%20in%20enumerate%28newedges%29%3A%0A%0A%20%20%20%20arr%5Bidx%5D%20%3D%20vertices%5Bnewedges%5Bidx%5D%5D%0A%0Alist.append%28arr%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=3&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false), your programm is already inside, press forward and wait for mistakes

Comment: no problem, good luck !
don't forget to close the question :)

Comment: I will, as soon as it is solved - the correct spelling does not solve it